# If the variable contains text within the string | HTML

Tags: php, html

I currently use this html code
`{{ou.user_agent}}`

Which results in the build which results in the user agent.

To identify an exact word I do this
`{{ou.user_agent == "Store" ? "Go" : "Nope"}}`

If the user agent contains Store exactly, it returns Go and if it does not, it returns Nop.

**The problem** with this is that it requires exactly the word.

**What I need is that of "Go" if "Store" is inside the string.**

What I need would be something like this in PHP but in HTML
Example code:

```
if(strpos($useragent, "Store") !== false){
//Note this is a demo code of what I want to achieve but in HTML
}
```

The detail is that it is in HTML and I don't know how to do it.

I am editing a template extension ".tpl.php" of Live Helper Chat

The code is outside the PHP tags as if it were HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: `ou.user_agent == "Store" ? "Go" : "Nope"` most certainly is JavaScript. HTML doesn't have this out of the box so you must be using some templating framework/library. You haven't shown which one, but it almost certainly uses JavaScript. (Also note that the highest scored answer there is exactly the answer of Gelu below, which you confirmed that works.)

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry, so I didn't know what language it was since it was outside the php fields as if it were html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `{{ou.user_agent.includes("Store") ? "Go" : "Nope"}}`

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have been asked many times before on Stack Overflow. Instead, flag them to be closed as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). See [answer].

Comment: It works thank you very much!
However, I find myself in doubt as to what language is this?
Is it HTML? because it is outside the PHP tags and has double brackets?

Comment: It's Javascript. You can't write complex logic in raw HTML.

Comment: @Ivar thanks for the heads-up, but I didn't have enough reputation points to flag posts. I do now :)

Comment: So to format it, do double brackets work?